# mi navbar no se pega a lo alto de la pantalla, deja un margen

Tags: html, html5, bootstrap-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]**Tengo una navbar pero no se pega a lo alto de la pantalla como deberia, deja un espacio**

```
<div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
                    <img class="d-inline-block align-text-top" src="../assets/logo.jpg" alt="logo 'Soy Bostero'" width="40" height="40">
                        Soy Bostero
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex flex-row gap-4">
                <li><a href="historial.html">Mi historial</a></li>
                <li><a href="datos.html">Mis datos</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagos.html">Pagos</a></li> 
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex flex-row gap-4">
                    <li class="navbar-right d-flex"><a href="#">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-right d-flex"><a href="#">Quiero asociarme</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Asi se ve, no se que me falta para lograr que ocupe ese espacio restante y por fin terminar con la nav

Comment: Solo quita la clase `p-2`... o si quieres mantener el `p-2`, el color azul del fondo colócalo al `<div>` que tiene la clase `p-2` (?...

Comment: `p` es por `padding`, por cierto. No está demás que revises [la documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding).

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es eliminar la clase `p-2` ya que este segnifica un espacio interior de 1rem a todos los lados del contenedor `div` si quieres conservar este espacio puedes añadirlo en el contenedor `nav` (por ejemplo `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top p-2"`)

Aqui esta tu códico con el espacio interior dentro del navbar

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top p-2">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.html">
                    <img class="d-inline-block align-text-top" src="../assets/logo.jpg" alt="logo 'Soy Bostero'" width="40" height="40">
                        Soy Bostero
                </a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex flex-row gap-4">
                <li><a href="historial.html">Mi historial</a></li>
                <li><a href="datos.html">Mis datos</a></li>
                <li><a href="pagos.html">Pagos</a></li> 
            </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex flex-row gap-4">
                    <li class="navbar-right d-flex"><a href="#">Iniciar sesion</a></li>
                    <li class="navbar-right d-flex"><a href="#">Quiero asociarme</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```